# Facing this issue: pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pygame, compilation, pycharm

I have written this code but I am facing issues:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            running = False
```

Comment: May i know things like your operating system (Windows, Linux, Mac) and your GPU specifications.

Comment: Can you also explain what the difficulty is, like does the window even appear?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

change
`if event.type == pygame.quit():`
to
`if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`